# "Sysprep" for Linux after cloning VMs?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7

If I clone a Windows VM (Server or Desktop), I need to perform a "sysprep" to change SID.

Wondering that if I clone a Linux VM, is there anything similar to "sysprep" must be done?

I am using CentOS 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's exactly what `virt-sysprep` is for.

From the [man page](http://libguestfs.org/virt-sysprep.1.html):

> Virt-sysprep can reset or unconfigure a virtual machine so that clones can be made from it. Steps in this process include removing SSH host keys, removing persistent network MAC configuration, and removing user accounts. Virt-sysprep can also customize a virtual machine, for instance by adding SSH keys, users or logos. Each step can be enabled or disabled as required.

You can use `virt-sysprep` on any disk image format that your version of qemu understands. This usually includes raw disk images, qcow2, VMware VMDK, Windows VHD, VirtualBox VDI, and many others.

Comment: Hi Michael, are there any tools with the same purpose for Ubuntu?

Comment: @OgrishMan What's wrong with virt-sysprep?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't make it clear. I mean this question is tagged with `centos` so I don't know if it can be used on Ubuntu. I already searched around and found it can also be used on Ubuntu. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that you will find is used for parts of this task.  Though it is more focused on handling the tasks after the image has been restored.